# Redefine \maketitle error if author is not defined

Tags: titles

I've redefined \maketitle, but I want to make optional the field @author or @date because when I don't define them I get the error:

> There's no line here to end. (\maketitle[toc=off] ...)

The code is:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle[1][]{
{\raggedright
\begin{center}
{\Huge \textit{\textbf{\@title}}}\\[4ex]
{\Large \@author}\\[2ex]
{\large \@date}\\[12ex]
\end{center}
{\ifstrequal{#1}{toc=on}{\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{\fill} \tableofcontents \vspace*{\fill} \newpage}{}} \pagenumbering{arabic}
}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You could just set the initial value of `\@author` and `\@date` to an empy string.

Comment: I think the problem is \\[4ex] because when author is not defined there's no line to end

Comment: Ok, with the default definition of `\maketitle` within `article` class it is possible to set `\author{} \date{}`. You could look in that code, how it is done. And provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. Or use `\author{\strut}\date{\strut}`.